# Limit No. of CPU in C

Tags: c, testing, cpu, execution

I was testing a c code on a physical and virtual machine and i need to limit the no. of cpu used during execution of c program. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Linux there is `sched_setaffinity`. For instance if you want it to run just on CPUs 1 and 3:

```
cpu_set_t set;

CPU_ZERO(&set);
CPU_SET(1, &set);
CPU_SET(3, &set);

sched_setaffinity(pid, CPU_SETSIZE, &set);
```

Caution: `sched_setaffinity` and `sched_getaffinity` are Linux-specific (they don't exist on other POSIX systems).

On BSDs there is **[`cpuset_setaffinity`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpuset_setaffinity&sektion=2)** with similar semantics. I expect Solaris to have a similar feature.

Answer (score 6):

Not platform-independently, but in Windows, you can use [`SetProcessAffinityMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
SetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), 0x1); //Only CPU #1
```